# unable to access chrome://apps or chrome://extension using button click from a react chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I want to add a button on my react new tab chrome extension and on button click I want to redirect to Chrome://apps or extension page. But it's not working its showing unable to access local resources.